# readline chops my console input off when I do ctrl+C / ctrl+V on gnome terminal

Tags: gnome, readline

Environment:
  Ubuntu 10.04 LTS
  Gnome Desktop v2.30.2
  gcc/g++ 4.4.3
  libreadline 6.1

I was building an application that inputs a multiple line of input and process for it and I found that if the size of input is large, readline skips several bytes of characters. To make sure, I made a simple program like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <readline/readline.h>
int main() {
    while (1) {
        char *p = readline("> ");
        if (!p) break;
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", p);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and generated 20000 lines of input, which consists of 120000 bytes.

```
seq -f "%05g" 1 20000 >gen.txt
```

and ran the test program on gnome terminal and performed copy-and-paste of the content of gen.txt:

```
g++ test.cpp -lreadline
./a.out 2>out.txt
[copy-and-paste the content of gen.txt]
```

I could see that out.txt was smaller than gen.txt, and many bytes are omitted.

```
wc -c out.txt
119966 out.txt
```

I want to know which component is flawed, whether gnome terminal or readline, and want to know how many bytes of clipboard content readline and gnome terminal assure that copy-and-paste can be done in that amount without problem.

Comment: How about first test with `cat > out2.txt` and then paste. This will check if the terminal works properly. Also you should probably paste into an editor also, to verify the original copy operation went properly.

Comment: I did some more tests; 1. paste into cat > out2.txt on gnome terminal, 2. paste on vim 3. paste on gedit. for all these three tests, paste worked perfectly and there were no character loss. that is why I am suspicious about readline library.